# How to make the path auto in the components in vue?

Tags: vue.js

If I use a component in different path.the images in the component can not auto fix the path.

for example:

`<img src="../icon.png" />` in the folder `wwwroot` is ok.

but if there is another html detail.html in the `wwwroot/detail` folder.

`it is <img src="../../icon.png" />` also will be ok.

but it can not auto fix the path. need I specify the path as a variable every time?

I am not using the node and `vue cli` just `vue` single page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an absolute path to the resource. An absolute path begins with `/` and will always point to the same location regardless of the location of the webpage.

Assuming you have `wwwroot/detail/icon.png` in your filesystem and `wwwroot` is hosted at the root, then you can reference the image like this:

```html
<img src="/detail/icon.png">
```

Comment: it will give a error that : file:///detail/icon.png ERR_File_NOT_FOUND

Comment: I don't know what your directory layout is; just make sure the path points to the file. This will not work if your webpage is not hosted by a web server like apache, nginx, etc. It looks like you have just opened the .html file directly in the browser.